# Grep not Giving expected result while using pipe

Tags: linux, grep

I'm running below command,but it returns empty.

`grep -i -e "abc()|daf()|newname|" test.txt`

test.txt contains below data.

```
abc()
daf()
blahblah
newname
```

I'm getting output empty but expecting to return the string, could someone please explain or share why not getting desired output. ThankYou!!

Answer (score 0):

From the `grep(1)` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep);

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, **|**, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions ?, +, {, |, (, and ).

There are 2 options;

1. Use an extended regex `-E` to 'enable' the `|`'s

   ```sh
   grep -i -E "abc()|daf()|newname" test.txt
   ```

   [What is the difference between grep -e and grep -E option?](https://%5Bunix.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-e-and-grep-e-option)
2. Escape the `|` to keep using regular regex `-e`:

   ```sh
   grep -i -e "abc()\|daf()\|newname" test.txt
   ```

Both options will result in :

```
abc()
daf()
newname
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X1lRPykzTz8JyOHiUlZwSU0qTVcoSS0u0SupKOFKTc7IV1BKTErW0FRS4LSzQ5dJSUzDIZOUk5gBwkoKmHJ5qeV5ibmpaPrAtufmKxhCVUE4SlzpRakFCrqZCrqpUJfE1ICtjamBm4NhhhHEDJCWmDyICJJBrlCDIOZgGvP/PwA)